# why I get blank page when I browse to localhost:3000?

Tags: reactjs

trying this react example after I start the server at port 3000 I get a blank page. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="app"></div>

      <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(

          <h1>Hello React</h1>,
          document.getElementById('app')
        );

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So why I get blank page ?

I see there is an error in the console but I dont know if this is the problem or not. I am on windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems last version of babel has a problem I switched to 5.8.23 and I get "Hello Ract" normally !!